# Half-combed cat

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat is a european shorthair. I'm able to comb my cat's right side hair successfully, but when I try to comb his left side, I perceive he doesn't want because he throws himself laying on that side, hence he gets combed on the right side only! Could that is an issue, or just it's a strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Signs of illness/discomfort in your cat includes:

- change in eating habits or not eating
- decreased activity
- hiding in places for a long time
- sleeping for a long time

Check the skin on the left side for any irregularities or lesions. If you suspect there is something internal to the cat that may cause it to favor one side, I guess the only way to know for sure is to let the vet run some scans on it.

If there are no medical issues, it could be that he just really prefers the combing sensation on one side.

Comment: None of these signs affect my cat, except "sleeping for a long time". However, he has always slept for as such time, he hasn't changed his habits lastly. Also, he always preferred to get combed on the right side. Do you think it could be a serious problem?